# is it possible to install upm for micropython? if so how?

Tags: python, iot, sensors, micropython

I am wondering if it is possible to install upm package for micropython

https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/upm/tree/master/examples/python

and if so, if anyone has any idea how?

Comment: It looks to me as if the upm Python package is a Python binding for a [whole load of drivers written in C](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/upm) that in turn depend on something called [MRAA](https://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/) that runs on Linux, so even if you could install the Python package I don't think that'll get you anywhere on any Micropython platform. What platform are you actually using and what devices do you want to talk to?

Comment: Thanks...this really isnt my area of expertise.. I "want" to use a pyboard to interface with a LSM6DSL gyro/accelerometer. I was attempting to comprehend the datasheet to see if I could write my own i2c scripts in micropython but really don't know alot about deciphering which registers/values to write to control it the way I want. Luckily there is a UPM python script that does exactly this, but I might have to resort to a RPi or something of the sort

Comment: From a quick look at the datasheet it won't be a trivial task to write your own driver for that sensor, at least if you need its full functionality. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. The `upm` Python package appears to be a a Python binding for a [collection of drivers written in C](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/upm) that in turn depend on something called [MRAA](https://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/) that's written to run under Linux, so even if you could install the Python package I don't think that'll get you anywhere on any MicroPython platform.

If what you're actually interested in is a specific device, such as the LSM6DSL inertial measurement unit, you could look for an existing MicroPython driver for that, or for help writing one yourself - I found [a post about this sensor](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=6720&p=38259&hilit=lsm6dsl#p38259) on the MicroPython forum, so you could try asking there.

Otherwise if you need to use upm I think you'll have to move to a Linux-based platform such as the Raspberry Pi.